# How to make visible only button image?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles

I have "Save" button which has two states: invisible (when no changes) and visible: when some text changed.

So, I create XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="btnSaveText"                                                                               
        Grid.Column="0"                                          
        VerticalAlignment="Center"                                                                          
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="0,0,1,0" Width="22" Height="22" Padding="0"
        BorderBrush="#EFF4FA"
        Background="#EFF4FA"                                                                                                                   IsEnabled="False"                                        
        Style="{StaticResource stlButton}">
        <Image Source="/UI.Resources;component/PNGImages/Save.png" 
               Style="{StaticResource stlButtonImage}" />
</Button>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="stlButtonImage">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="None" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="stlButton">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EFF4FA"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EFF4FA"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But, when the button is disabled it looks like this:
[image: SaveButton]

How to make visible only button image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Button`s Background to `Transparent` :

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
```

Full sample:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="stlButton">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />

            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EFF4FA"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you also want to get rid of the `Border` you could link it to the `Background` that will make it invisible, too:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="stlButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
             </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```